# How can I find my hideout?

Tags: assassins-creed-syndicate

There are times where I need to return to my hideout, but since it's a moving train I often find myself searching for it on the map. This is not always easy, since the map is filled with different icons.

I was wondering if there was a button to instantly fast-travel to my hideout without even knowing where it is, or at the very least a button that allows me to center the map around my hideout. I'm playing on PS4, but feel free to answer for Xbox or PC for any future visitors who might be curious.

Alternatively, I'd also accept an answer that shows me the route my hideout will take around London. That should help me find it more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there's no button that will jump right to your hideout.  The hideout follows the train tracks around the city, so you can typically look for the nearest track on the map and then follow the loop.

That said, when I played, I sometimes couldn't find the icon *anywhere* - I think there are bugs in the game that sometimes prevent it from showing up on the map.

This is probably one of my top 5 frustrations with the game, sadly.

Comment: Yes, about the bug and the icon not showing - I experienced the same on PS4: what usually helped for me was to time travel to any location, after that time travel, re-open the map again and you should see the train icon somewhere on the map.